# Error: Error { kind: ToSql(0), cause: Some(WrongType { postgres: Json, rust: "alloc::string::String" }) }

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

I have tried to insert json value into my table and got error

```
async fn insert_values(client: &Client, user: Report) -> Result<(), Error> {
    // Serialize the user data to JSON
    let user_json = json!({
        "username": user.username,
        "gender": {
            "val": user.gender.val,
        },
    });
     let res = serde_json::to_string(&user_json ).unwrap();
    // Execute the SQL statement to insert values
    client
        .execute("INSERT INTO users (user_report) VALUES ($1)", &[&res])
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

like this `Error: Error { kind: ToSql(0), cause: Some(WrongType { postgres: Json, rust: "alloc::string::String" }) }`

here is create table function

```
async fn create_table(client: &Client) -> Result<(), Error> {
    // Define the SQL statement to create a table if it doesn't exist
    let command = r#"
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            user_report JSONB
        )"#;

    // Execute the SQL statement to create the table
    client.execute(command, &[]).await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

and Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
serde = {version = "1.0.164", features=["derive"]}
serde_json = "1.0.103"
tokio-postgres = [version = "0.7.10", features= ["with-serde_json-1"]]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

output error is `Error: Error { kind: ToSql(0), cause: Some(WrongType { postgres: Json, rust: "alloc::string::String" }) }` , code side is compiled without any errors but in posgre itself some this kind of error appears

Comment: Shouldn't you rather use https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/tokio_postgres/types/struct.Json.html instead of serializing to string?

Comment: use tokio_postgres::types::Json;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Json` in `types`

Comment: Interesting. This type seems to have disappeared from `postgres_types`. Investigating.

Comment: Ah, it requires feature `with-serde_json-1`.

Comment: got it thank u so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, looks like `Json` is not necessary if feature flag `with-serde_json-1` is activated. Consequently, I'll suggest using @pr0gramista's answer, which is slightly more concise.

---

`tokio-postgres` has a `struct` `Json`, hidden behind feature flag `with-serde_json-1`.

```rust
use tokio_postgres::types::Json;


async fn insert_values(client: &Client, user: Report) -> Result<(), Error> {
    // Serialize the user data to JSON
    let user_json = Json(json!({ // <-- `Json` can be bound into SQL.
        "username": user.username,
        "gender": {
            "val": user.gender.val,
        },
    }));
    // Execute the SQL statement to insert values
    client
        .execute("INSERT INTO users (user_report) VALUES ($1)", &[&user_json])
        .await?;
    Ok(()
}
```

I'm using the following dependencies

```ini
[dependencies]
serde = "1.0.192"
serde_json = "1.0.108"
tokio = { version = "1.33.0", features = ["full"] }
tokio-postgres = { version = "0.7.10", features = ["with-serde_json-1"] }
```

Comment: got it thank u so much

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [trait implementation](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/master/postgres-types/src/serde_json_1.rs) I see that the trait ToSql is implemented for [serde_json Value enum](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/index.html), not String.

If you have a struct that implements Serialize you can serialize it to Value using `serde_json::to_value(...)`.

You can skip serialization to String and pass Value directly:

```rust
async fn insert_values(client: &Client, user: Report) -> Result<(), Error> {
    // Serialize the user data to JSON
    let user_json = json!({
        "username": user.username,
        "gender": {
            "val": user.gender.val,
        },
    });
    // Execute the SQL statement to insert values
    client
        .execute("INSERT INTO users (user_report) VALUES ($1)", &[&user_json])
        .await?;
    Ok(()
}
```

Comment: 6 |         .execute("INSERT INTO users (user_report) VALUES ($1)", &[&user_json])
   |                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ToSql` is not implemented for `serde_json::Value` 

this error occurs

Comment: Did you by any chance remove `with-serde_json-1`? This solution works for me.